# Windows 10 Universal App C# SQLite classes

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am building a Windows Universal App using Visual Studio 2015, C#.
I have installed `SQLite for Universal App Platform vsix file` that I downloaded from official SQLite website.
I have added the reference to this in my solution.

My problem is this:
I cannot add the `using System.Data.SQLite;` line, it says "Type or namespace SQLite does not exist in namespace System.Data".

Should I add another reference, or install another extension for Visual Studio? Note that I am making a Universal App, so I need extensions that are made to work across all devices running Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and came up with adding a Nuget package to the references as well. You can try[SQLite.NET-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL) or [SQLite.NET.Async-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL) for example.